# SmartAdmin for Angular 2 support by Angular 4 or not?

Tags: angular

I am using Smart-Admin for Angular 2. Now we are planning to move our product from angular 2 to 4. So before moving i want to check whether the smart-admin what we have purchased is supported by angular 4 or not otherwise we can't go for angular 4.

So if anybody has any idea about this is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

As angular2 and angular4 are almost identical (4 being newer and updated) unlike angularjs. Meaning anything that works in angular2 *should* therefore work in angular4.

However, I cant say for certain as i have never used Smart-Admin.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of SmartAdmin includes an Angular 4 template.